# How to detect notification from WebView in android?

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, notifications

I am working on a chat like app. In this I want to open a chat module in the webview (in android). WebView is working fine, chat notifications are working correctly too.

But I want to detect webview's notification from my app class.
Whenever a notification occurs, my app should get it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` is handling notifications "by own", you can detect new/removed them using [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService)

Comment: WebView is handling them, but how my app will know that WebView got a new notification.

Comment: you won't know, there is no API in `WebView` for notifications, you can only detect them when posted in system